# How to display data of another table in grid view in yii2?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

In `siteController` I write query and pass array of `dataProvider` to `index.php` to display contain in table form. In `index.php` I want to display `member name` instead of `memberID`. For that I have write inner query and which is successfully run on command prompt successfully.Here I am not able to print `first name` instead of '`member id`'

```
      public function actionIndex()
      {              
     $query = new \yii\db\Query;
      $query->select(['member.firstName',
                    'complaint.practiceCode','complaint.id',
                    'complaint.description','member.firstName'])
           ->from(['complaint'])
           ->innerJoin(['member','complaint.memberID = member.id'])
           ->groupBy(['complaint.id'])
           ->where(['complaint.deleted' => 'N']);
     $query->createCommand();
```

Here I have pass data by creating  `$dataProvider4` but I am not able to set value  of `firstName` instead of `memberID`.

```
      $dataProvider4= new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => false,
       ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
       'dataProvider4'=>$dataProvider4]);

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider4,
    'summary'=>'Total'.'&nbsp<b>'.$complaintModel.'</b>&nbsp'.'Complaints',
    'columns' => [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           'practiceCode',
            // 'memberID',
            'description',
            'status',
       ],
    ]); ?>
```

I have pass data through the dataProvider.

Comment: post full code of gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a powerful framework, then you'd be better to let the framework do the complicated thing for you, rather than trying to write your own queries. It's what Yii was designed for. Try this in your action.

```
public function actionIndex()
    {              
    $query = Member::find()->
        ->select(['firstName', complaint.practiceCode', complaint.id', 'complaint.description'])
        ->groupBy(['complaint.id'])
        ->joinWith('complaints')//Tells Yii to use the complains relation that we define below. By default it is an inner join
        ->where(['complaint.deleted' => 'N']);

$dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => false,
]);

return $this->render('index', [
    'dataProvider4'=>$dataProvider]);
```

In your model you will need to define a relation that you can use in the query;

```
public function getComplaints(){
    return $this->hasMany(Complaints::className(), 'memberID' => 'id');
}
```

This is useful as it will allow you to get complaints without having to write your own query to get them.

Yii will sort out all the column names for you, and write the query.

Answer (score 0):

The query is not related to dataProvider and then is unuseful

If you want extend the query you should do this and assign to the query used in dataprovider not only perform a query. 
Anyway you can get the name of the member using an anonymous function retrieve the value;

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider4,
        //'summary'=>'Total'.'&nbsp<b>'.$complaintModel.'</b>&nbsp'.'Complaints',
        'columns' => [
           ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           'practiceCode',
          /* ['attribute' => '',
            'value' => function ($model) {
               $myMemberModel =  Member::find()->
                       where(['id'=> $model->memberID ])->one();
               if (isset($myMemberModel) {
                  return $myMemberModel->firtsName;
               } else {
                 return ' id : '.  $model->memberID . ' do not match ';
               }
             }],*/
              'firstName',
               'memberID',
              'description',
              'status',
              ],
         ]); 
?>
```

Comment: Actually I have pass data through the dataProvider. I am not added above this dataProvider function ......I added this grid view change but yet not working

Comment: I have update the answer using Member for retrieve the username .

Comment: Error:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: At this line got error:return Member::find()->where(['id' =>$model->memberID])->one()->firtsName;

Comment: I have update the answer ... a mistake value instead of 'value'

Comment: I have update the answer checking if the memberID match with member.id

Comment: I have modified the answer avoiding $model->memberID ... try and give me a feedback

Comment: OK then the problem is related to the field name of the field memberID, please show me the Member model

Comment: In member model 'id' instead of **memberID** and **memberID** is fk in Complaint

Comment: I have update the asnwer whit memberId try if is right otherwise you should use tha same name you have in model Complaint for member ID. show both the model Member and Complaint if you don find the right fields name

Comment: Complaint model:return [
            [['practiceCode', 'memberID'], 'integer'],
            [['description', 'comment', 'status', 'deleted'], 'string'],
            [['created', 'updated'], 'safe'],
            [['sendTo'], 'string', 'max' => 1],
            [['caption'], 'string', 'max' => 200]
        ];

Comment: Please show the query you use for the dataProvider.. of the code of the this action in controller..

Comment: Already I have added query and **dataProvider** in above code I have write this code in **siteController** because I want to display data on **index.php**

Comment: Yes but i can't see all the action i see only the query. I can't check ho you converted this to the dataProvider.. lem me see this action code.. please.

Comment: public function actionIndex()
    {$query = new \yii\db\Query;

Comment: Try commenting the attribute value code and add a simple firstName field.. see my updated answer..

Comment: PS you have two time member.firstName ,,, try deleting one

Comment: @priyankaahire explain better i don't understand, work or not.?

Comment: sorry, I will explain

Comment: I remove duplicate entry of member.firstName from code.and as per you told me I add 'firstName' in gridView.After done this all changes I got a result but one problem in that is

Comment: Problem:Display same Member name  for all entry

Comment: Try uncomment memberID.. if this value don't change mean your query obtain this result ... I  Have update the answer..

Comment: @scaisEdge, I was wondering, Will it query the database for each memberID? Or is the joined model is retrieved as an array?

Comment: @RameshPareek I don't understand ... what you are referring ..eventually . post a proper question ..